# Need help in this Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

The regular expression I am using:

```
%s??[a-z](:\d+|)(^\[)?
```

The string is:

```
"%sprix is the %s[4] online %s[3]:6 pshopping %s:9 in %s"
```

I am trying to find all `%s` from string except `%s[4]` and `%s[3]`.

My output using the above regular expression is not giving expected results.

Expected Output is:

```
%s, %s:9, %s
```

My Output is:

```
%s, %s[ , %s[, %s:9, %s
```

Comment: What do you want to match in the above string? See https://regex101.com/r/i0dfOJ/1

Comment: I have added kindly check it

Comment: Why do you need to parse an already formatted string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
%s(?!\[)(?::\d+)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i0dfOJ/2).

**Details**:

- `%s` - a percentage sign and `s`
- `(?!\[)` - that is not followed with `[`
- `(?::\d+)?` - an optional sequence of a `:` and one or more digits

The above regex will fail the match in all cases when `%s` is followed with `[`, e.g. in `%s[text`. If you only want to fail the match when `%s` is followed with `[`+number+`]`, use `%s(?!\[\d+\])(?::\d+)?`.

Comment: FYI, this will fail the match in all cases when `%s` is followed with `[`, e.g. in `%s[text`. If you only want to fail the match when `%s` is followed with `[`+number+`]`, use `%s(?!\[\d+\])(?::\d+)?`.